# Using ProcessBuilder to run ImageMagick command

Tags: java, imagemagick, processbuilder

I am trying to run a simple ImageMagick command from a Java class and as I have to run only a few commands I thought instead of using Im4Java ,I could directly use ProcessBuilder.start().
I am using the following code-

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("convert","pic2.png","pic52.png");
          pb.directory(new File("/user/gaurav_kl"));
         pb.start();
```

but I am getting the error 
IOException - Cannot run program "convert" (in directory "/user/gaurav_kl"): error=2, No such file or directory
What could be the reason.
when I run the same command from terminal it works fine from any Dir as IM has been added to classpath

Comment: imagemagic has about a hundred followers, processbuilder has about 0, you are flying under the radar with this question

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of ProcessBuilder when searching for a command executable is system/jvm dependent. While you might expect that it uses same logic as the underlying shell (i.e. BASH), there is no guarantee of it in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Based on your experience (and others), it is better to provide the complete command path. For example:

```
String IMGK_PATH="/usr/local/magick/bin";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(IMGK_PATH + "/convert","pic2.png","pic52.png");
pb.directory(new File("/user/gaurav_kl"));
pb.start();
```

Comment: Thank you! Trawled for days before I found your solution